# Adding params into href url

Tags: html, url, grails, href

I want to be able to pass form values through an `href url`.

This is what I am trying:

```
<a href="/scholarshipsystem/personalInformation/save?${'#piForm1'}.serialize()" rel="tooltip" title="Save and return later"><center>Save</center></a>
```

This takes me to `scholarshipsystem/personalInformation/save?#piForm1.serialize()`

I've tried manipulating this in different ways but I just can't figure it out.

Comment: `#ipForm1` is something that is client-side not server-side. You need to use jQuery not GSP to do that.

Comment: Do you want to submit the form on the click on hyperlink or you just want to add some parameters in the link.

Answer (score -1):

Try This:

```
<g:link controller="controllerName" action="actionName"  params="[key1: value1,key2:value2]" >Save </g:link>
```

Enjoy.

Comment: With this link you can't send form values, since the form values are not given from the user when *.gsp is parsed and transformed into html.

Comment: @MarioDavid: His question was to send params in anchor link, not submit form.

Answer (score -1):

To append form input elements to a url, you can use use a normal html form with the attribute method and set it to "get" like the following:

```
<form method="get" action="http://www.google.de">
  <input type="text" name="q">
  <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

For this to achieve, you don't need any javascript or jquery at all.

Comment: This is not the question he asked, and in grails if you want to make a form, you should follow this syntax.
`<g:form controller="controllerName" action="actionName">
  <g:textField name="fieldName"/>
  <g:submitButton name="submit"/>
 </g:form>`

Comment: he wrote: "to pass form values through an href url" - maybe i'm wrong here, but it sound to me that the user input of a form should be appended to an url. `${'#piForm1'}.serialize()` seems the approach to achieve exactly this (i'm guessing serialize() is the jquery [serialize](https://api.jquery.com/serialize/) method, that should be used here). I think the confusion just comes because of the assumtion, that `#piForm1` is the jquery selector rather than the anchor part of the url. As i wrote, this question isn't grails specific, so the answer applies to all forms, not just the "grails ones".